# How to Mock System.getProperty using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have added mock-maker-inline text in org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file and placed it in test/resources/mockito-extensions

In my test case I am using:

```
System system = mock(System.class);
when(system.getProperty("flag")).thenReturn("true");`
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Why does it need to be mocked?  `System.setProperty("flag", "true");` should work in the set up of the test.

Answer (score 16):

Your could also use real methods, preparing and removing the configuration before and after each test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("flag", "true");
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    System.clearProperty("flag");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `System.getProperty()` method is *static*, in order to mock this you'll need to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock).

Here's an example:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void canMockSystemProperties() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        PowerMockito.when(System.getProperty("flag")).thenReturn("true");

        assertEquals("true", System.getProperty("flag"));
    }
}
```

This uses:

- `junit:junit:4.12`
- `org.mockito:mocktio-core:2.7.19`
- `org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.0`
- `org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.0`

Note: [@davidxxx's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529859/8200937) of avoiding the need to mock this by hiding all `System` access behind a facade is very sensible. Another way of avoiding the need to mock `System` is to actually set the desired value as a system property when running your test, [System Rules](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/) offers a neat way of setting up and tearing down System property expectations in the context of Junit tests.

Comment: System Rules is a JUnit add on but a really good add on. Fine to mention it as alternative.

Comment: Is it possible without using power mockito? as it's not recommended jar in my org.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito (1 as 2) doesn't provide a way to mock static methods.
So adding `mockito-inline` will be useless to mock the `System.getProperty()` method.

Generally, mocking static methods is often a bad idea as it encourages a bad design.
In your case, it is not the case as you need to mock a JDK class that you can of course not change.

So you have two ways :

- using Powermock or any tools that allows to mock static methods
- wrapping the System static method invocations in a class that provides instance methods, for example `SystemService`.

The last way is really not hard to implement and will besides provide a way to inject instance of this class where you need.
Which produces a much clearer code than a `system.getProperty("flag")` statement hidden between two statements.