# Is it possible to mock System.identityHashCode?

Tags: java, testing, mocking

Good day.

I have a tool which instruments objects in project by adding certain bytecode-generated `toString` implementation to each. The logic of generated `toString` is irrelevant but what important is that its return value depends on `System.identityHashCode` invocations, made inside.

Now I want to cover the generated logic with automated tests. I created a class for testing, generated `toString` for it and want to assert over its `toString` output. It's obvious that such test won't be reproducible, since `System.identityHashCode` gives different results between test runs.

Is it possible somehow to mock `System.identityHashCode` or stabilize the result it is given?

Comment: sounds like a bad test anyway, tbh. Can't you assert that the toString result contains some other useful value?

Comment: It might perhaps be possible to mock this with PowerMockito or similar reflection-based tools, but it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I have no choice. I know it is bad

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using Powermock, as described here: [How to Mock System.getProperty using Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529605/how-to-mock-system-getproperty-using-mockito/48529859#48529859)

However, the better approach would be to create a class that wraps `System` and then inject the wrapper into the class you are trying to test.

Then in your unit test you can inject a test implementation of the wrapper and control the output from System.

Comment: PowerMock is not my choice in this particular case, since I use JUnit5 which is not yet supported: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/830. Creating a separate class was not an option either: I want my generated toString logic to be as more independent from any non-standard abstractions (even introduced by me) as possible. Also, I cannot alter any class constructors or methods signatures to inject a thing into there. Thanks for answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a testing seam:

```
@Override public String toString() {
  return toString(System.identityHashCode(object));
}

/** Visible for testing. */
String toString(int hashCode) {
  // Your implementation here.
}
```

This way, you can call `toString(int)` as many times as you want from adjacent tests without concerning yourself with PowerMock or even Mockito.

As an alternative, if System.identityHashCode is used elsewhere in your class such that results need to be consistent, you can take a replacement [ToIntFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) in your constructor, and have the default implementation pass [System.identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-) as a [reference to a static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
public YourWrapperClass(Object object) {
  this(object, System::identityHashCode);
}

/** Visible for testing. */
YourWrapperClass(Object object, ToIntFunction<Object> hashCodeFunction) {
  this.object = object;
  this.hashCodeFunction = hashCodeFunction;
}
```